# I am getting run time error has :class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image

Tags: iphone, xcode

Let me provide brief intro to my project , I am displaying the image from the photo library , I have Imageview and button in my view controller , when i press the button it will navigate to photo library when i select the photo from library the image will be displayed in image view .

But when i run this project I am getting the runtime error please look at the code and suggest me solution , if am missing any file please inform me so that i can upload for your necessary.

I am not getting where exactly the error is, I googled and even saw the stack overflow still i can't find any solution

Following are the Viewcontroller.m file and the console look at the error and please tell me

```
view controller.m 


//
//  ViewController.m
//  ImagePicker
//
//  Created by Vaibhav on 12/30/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imagepic;


-(IBAction)ButtonClicked{



    ipc=  [UIImagePickerController alloc];
    ipc.delegate=self;

    ipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES ];



}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imagepic.image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage ];
    [ [picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];

    [picker release];


}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [ [picker parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
    [picker release];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Error message on Console:

```
2012-12-30 13:03:05.758 ImagePicker[1409:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x687b2e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13b9052 0x154ad0a 0x13b8f11 0x9b0032 0x921f7b 0x921eeb 0x93cd60 0x22f91a 0x13bae1a 0x1324821 0x22e46e 0xd5e2c 0xd63a9 0xd65cb 0x36a73 0x36ce2 0x36ea8 0x3dd9a 0xebe6 0xf8a6 0x1e743 0x1f1f8 0x12aa9 0x12a3fa9 0x138d1c5 0x12f2022 0x12f090a 0x12efdb4 0x12efccb 0xf2a7 0x10a9b 0x1d02 0x1c75)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewController.xib`, select your image view and check for `IBOutlet Connections`. If it is connected to an `IBOutlet` named `image`, remove it. Your image view should be connected to an `IBOutlet` that you have in corresponding `.h` file. You probably had renamed `UIImageView` to `imagePic` which was previously `image`.

Comment: Yes Now I can compile but in console it is showing me that darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1520. i can't see photo library still..

Comment: How long it will take to load?

Comment: Anybody there to reply question??